# Should I use a comma before and (Comma Before And in Lists) in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, lists

Grammarly advices me to add `,` before `and` in the following phrases and sentences with the following comment

> It seems that this sentence contains a series of three or more words,
> phrases, or clauses. Consider inserting a comma to separate the
> elements.

But I believe it's not necessary. Am I wrong?

[Comma Before And](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-and/)

[What Is the Oxford Comma (or Serial Comma)?](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/)

- Methodology for field measurements of current, wave **and** tide
- This report aims to illustrate the methodology of measuring waves,
  currents **and** tides in the desired region for the Sirik water
  reservoir.
- Collecting and investigating the available information, primary
  assessment of installation location **and** design of installation set-up
- The equipment for wave, current **and** tide measurements in Sirik study
  area
- It is obvious that depending on the quality and method of processing
  and representing the information, in-depth analysis,
  interpretation **and** control of the results will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first link answers this:

> It’s almost always optional to put a comma before and in a list.

Your second link then goes on to say

> Unless you’re writing for a particular publication or drafting an essay for school, whether or not you use the Oxford comma is generally up to you. However, omitting it can sometimes cause some strange misunderstandings.

And so Grammarly suggests using the serial comma.